# AWS CDK: Is there a way to create database schema using CDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created a RDS Aurora Postgres Database Cluster and Database Instance through CDK (using java as a language). Now I am trying to achieve creating a database schema through CDK. I tried but did not find any documentation or help anywhere which tells

1. If at all it is possible to create DB schema through CDK for RDS databases?
2. If so, how?
3. If not, what are the best practices for this to achieve?

If anyone has already done it or has knowledge, I will appreciate pointing me to right direction.

Thanks,
Horizon7

Answer (score 13):

The CDK itself does not have an out of the box solution for creating SQL schemas as it is used for managing the provisioning of infrastructure.

However, there is a tool for creating additional processes, this tool is a [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudformation.CustomResource.html).

A `CustomResource` will allow you to invoke a Lambda function, this function could be developed to perform SQL interaction with the RDS instance and then create the schemas.

If you enable [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) your Lambda function should be able to interact with the RDS instance without any additional considerations for networking. As long as it has the IAM permissions it can invoke the commands.

Comment: Thanks Chris Williams for responding. I will try that out.

Comment: There's an [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/use-aws-cdk-to-initialize-amazon-rds-instances/) of this solution in the Amazon docs.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that you could store your database credentials securely in AWS Secrets Manager and use a CloudFormation custom resource or an AWS SDK script that runs after your CDK deployment to create the schema. This method is more manual and requires you to manage the lifecycle of the schema creation process outside of CDK but can be more flexible for complex deployments.